# Wordpress - auto login from another site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a custom crm site over customers.

My customers use wordpress, and I would like to click on a button and login.
Example like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://customersite.com/wp-admin" class="login-form" role="form">
    <input name="email" id="email" value="example@customer.dk"/>
    <input name="password" id="password" value="password_123"/>
    <button type="submit">Login on wordpress</button>
</form>
```

So the login information changes if im on customer.php?id=2 and customer.php?id=3
Hope you understand

Comment: You should look into wp_set_auth_cookie... See https://carlofontanos.com/auto-login-to-wordpress-from-another-website/

Comment: You might want to move this question to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/